# AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'drivername' using Flask SqlAlchemy

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to connect to a MySQL database using Flask-SqlAlchemy, here's my parameter :

```
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'mysql://root:pass@127.0.0.1/database?charset=utf8'
```

But when I go to the url, I get this error :

> AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'drivername'

If I change the `SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI` to `sqlite:///db.sqlite`, it works correctly.

What am I missing ?

Note: I also tried `mysql+mysqldb://`, without any luck.

Comment: Just a guess: you don't by any chance have an extra comma after your URL string, do you?

Comment: Man you're good ! :) (You can answer it, I'll upvote & validate the answer :))

Comment: Can be put on hold under the official close reason: _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error._

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This error often comes up due to their being an extra comma after the URL string. So, instead of...

```
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'mysql://root:pass@127.0.0.1/database?charset=utf8'
```

...you have...

```
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'mysql://root:pass@127.0.0.1/database?charset=utf8',
```

The extra comma turns the SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI into a tuple with the string as the only value. SQLAlchemy will skip trying to parse the resulting tuple, but Flask-SQLAlchemy will still try to use the "parsed" result.

This is fixed by removing the extra comma.

Comment: You're right, I switched from a dict configuration to an Object configuration, and I forgot to remove some coma... hence the error ... Thanks !

Comment: Your answer solved a totally different problem that I have been with a SQLAlchemy result, just realising its a tuple helped get my value! ie Go for myresult[0] instead of myresult

Comment: Thank you very much! I can only imagine how much time this issue would have taken from me to find it!

Comment: Clearly, the error message should link directly to this answer.  Thank you!